# JSF2.0 popup show after the second click

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have 3 managebean one model and 2 controllers  (1 for the popup text) i want a popup after i insert into the database.

my page is like this the problem is that when i call for mensaje.mostrar() i works but when i try to call cursoControlador.registrarCurso() and from there try to call mensaje.mostrar() that changes the value from mostrarMensaje (boolean) don't show the popup.

```
<ui:define name="centro">
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">

            <p:outputLabel value="Nombre" />
            <p:inputText value="#{cursoModelo.nombre}"/>
```

this is the button use and works fine

```
<p:commandButton action="#{mesaje.mostrar()}" value="Registrar Curso" >
    <f:ajax render="@form"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

and this is the behavior i want

```
<p:commandButton action="#{cursoControlador.registrarCurso()}" value="Registrar Curso" >
    <f:ajax render="@form"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

and this is the popup message i want to show

```
    </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="fondo-popup" rendered="#{mensaje.mostrarMensaje}">
            <div class="panel-popup">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{mensaje.texto}"/>
                <h:commandButton value="Aceptar" action="#{mensaje.esconder()}">
                    <f:ajax render="@form"/>
                </h:commandButton>
            </div>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>

</ui:define>
```

model

```
@Named(value = "cursoModelo")
@SessionScoped
public class CursoModelo implements Serializable {

    private String nombre;
    //getters and setters...
}
```

controller 1

```
@Named(value = "cursoControlador")
@SessionScoped
public class CursoControlador implements Serializable{
    @Inject private CursoModelo cursoModelo;
    @Inject private Mensaje mensaje;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of CursoControlador
     */
    public CursoControlador() {
    }

    public String registrarCurso(){
        //SOME CODE that inserts into de database
        mensaje.mostrar(); //this is the problem probably i'm doing it wrong
        return "index";
    }
}
```

controller 2 (The controller for the message)

```
@Named(value = "mensaje")
@SessionScoped
public class Mensaje implements Serializable {

    private String texto;
    private boolean mostrarMensaje;
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of Mensaje
     */
    public Mensaje() {
        texto = "Mensaje a mostrar";
        mostrarMensaje = false;
    }

    public void mostrar(){
        mostrarMensaje = true;
    }

    public void esconder(){
        mostrarMensaje = false;
    }
    //getters and setters from texto and mostrarMensaje
}
```

Comment: We are not able to understand what you want, because their is no popup(Dialog box), As far as i know we show the popup show when user perfomr some action and on action event we write code to show the popup.

Are you trying to create dialog like this https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml

Comment: @ankushyadav: better to always ask for a [mcve] (type [ mcve ] without the spaces in a comment)

Comment: @ankushyadav Thanks i'll rewrite the question